# Python find content between to different separators - without bs4

Tags: python, split

I have been searching for it and haven't found exactly the answer for this issue. I would like to find the content in between `<start_here>` and `<end_here>` in a string in python. This can happen several times in a string, an example would be:

```
"Text text text <start_here> bla bla bla <end_here> text text <start_here> bla2 bla2 bla2 <end_here>"
```

I am trying to extract "**bla bla bla**" and "**bla2 bla2 bla2**". The perk is that it would be ideal doing so without beautifulsoup4.

Any hints?

Cheers

Comment: So are `<start_here>` and `<end_here>` HTML tags? Why then the restriction on BeautifulSoup 4?

Comment: Whoever is downvoting could use some search and proof reading. This has not been discussed as I explained it. Good way of beefing up the community is giving a change to new arrivals to get some damn points on new questions!

Comment: @MartijnPieters they are not html tags per se, I created them to enclose information I need to extract somewhere else. I don't want to use Bs4 for several reasons, among them is portability and avoid using too many libs

Answer (score 2):

Use `re` module:

```
import re

a = "Text text text <start_here> bla bla bla <end_here> text text <start_here> bla2 bla2 bla2 <end_here>"

re.findall('<start_here>(.+?)<end_here>', a)
#[' bla bla bla ', ' bla2 bla2 bla2 ']
```

Comment: Grand! Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have made that like this (re.findall()):

```
import re
def findContentBetweenTags(txt, new_content, tag1, tag2=None):
        if tag2 == None:
            tag2=tag1
        pattern = "(?<=<"+tag1+">).*(?=</"+tag2+'>)'
        return re.findall(pattern,new_content, txt)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score -1):

Use regex with python including re module :

```
import re
print re.findall("<start_here>(.*?)<end_here>", "<start_here> test test <end_here>")
```

Comment: Why down vote? Could you provide information about down vote so I can improve the answer.

Comment: Works for me, thanks Emre! :) I don't have the reputation for upvote but you'd have it

Comment: I'm glad to see it helps :)